# clock chip (not the CPU clock) replacement on my BEMER medical device

Tags: computer-architecture

the 24 hour clock/timer on my BEMER PEMF device's microprocessor is keeping erratic time lately. Shortly after I reset to the correct time, it fails to keep accurate time.

I'm wondering if exposing the motherboard will allow me to easily identify and replace the clock chip? I am a newbie and have never done component level replacements, but am seeking to avoid BEMER's solution: Buy a new ($2600.00) control box with microprocessor.

Comment: `medical device` ponder legal liabilities. This is not a CS question. The solution may be as simple as replacing a battery - there may be no provision for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Chack battery if there is the provision to do so (as suggested by greybeard)

Check you have latest firmware.

Get a quote from third party repair technician (not always possible with medical equipment).

Pay the money to BEMER.

Attempt repair yourself – there are no youtube videos to help you.

```
If you fail, then BEMER may have to repair damage done by you plus the $2,600.
```

As pointed out by greybeard, as it’s a medical device, consider the legal liabilities if you seem to succeed and later find you haven’t.

This is a general list of some considerations for repairing equipment.
I’ve answered, though stated, this isn’t really a CS question.

Comment: thanx for your supererogation!  Harvey